# Vue router routes with similar pattern activate wrong route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have 3 routes with a similar pattern:

```
/resource/:type/:id (View3)
/resource/:type (View2)
/resource (View1)
```

However when I visit #2 it renders View2 correctly but complains about :id not being there, breaking the View.

```
vue-router.esm-bundler.js:1005 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Missing required param "id"
```

#1 and #3 work just fine. Here are the routes in question:

```
{
    path: '/resources/:resource/:id',
    name: 'ResultDetails',
    component: () => import('../views/ResultDetails.vue'),
    props: true
},
{
    path: '/resources/:resource',
    name: 'ResourceSearch',
    component: () => import('../views/ResourceSearch.vue'),
    props: true
},
{
    path: '/resources',
    name: 'Resources',
    component: () => import('../views/Resources.vue')
},
```

Am I missing something?

router links:

```
<router-link :to="'/resources/' + type" class="flex items-center break-words"></router-link>
<router-link :to="'/resources/' + type + '/' + id" class="flex items-center break-words"></router-link>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with [Vue Router 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-vite-starter-ywlldy?file=src%2FApp.vue) or [Vue Router 4](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-router-starter-yrqhp2?file=src%2FApp.vue).

Comment: If View2 gets rendered correctly (so the route matching works), then maybe you are using a wrong component inside View2?

If you have the possibility to change the `:to` parameter in your routes, use the object syntax to double check. Second link would look something like `:to="{ name: 'ResultDetails', params: { resource: type, id } }"`

Comment: @whereo I think that would work but I would have to change the route slightly, making a repeatable param, but not sure on the implementation. I tried it but gave me an error because 'resource' was an array and needed to be specified as a repeatable param on the route.